# C need suggestions on char connect and split function

Tags: c

I have a client that sends several chars and a server that splits them. I'm thinking using separators like  @@@first data.$$$ second data. &&& ID00001 *** the end.

But when data contains @$%*, this way won't work.

So any suggestions on what unique symbol I should choose as a separator? Or is there simple and powerful char functions like sscanf() to connect and split several chars?

Comment: There is no such thing, you have to write one for your specific case which is the plus side of not having a generic function that you can't optimize for the specific situation.

Comment: Maybe you should use the control characters such as: 0x1C U+001C FILE SEPARATOR,
0x1D U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR,
0x1E U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR,
0x1F U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 0):

if you cant use a modern serialization format like json or yaml how about

```
`0010first data0011second data`
```

etc. ie fixed length length length followed by string